# PHP str_replace() for appending to a url

Tags: php, append, embed, str-replace

I'm wondering if there's a better more 'safe' way to append a string to the src="" part of this soundcloud embed? As general users will be pasting in their SoundCloud embed codes into a field, I'm a bit worried about them changing the code and messing my str_replace() up:

```
$sc_preview_embed = '<iframe width="100%" height="166" scrolling="no" frameborder="no" src="https://w.soundcloud.com/player/?url=https%3A//api.soundcloud.com/tracks/110090423"></iframe>';

$sc_preview = str_replace('"></iframe>','&buying=false&download=true"></iframe>', $sc_preview_embed);
```

Is there a way of doing this using a wildcard so that I only append '&buying=false&download=true' to end of `src=""` in a user's embed code?

Comment: While I'm not familiar with the Soundcloud API and whatnot, I have a general question - do you need them to provide the full *html* code for embedding, or just the `trackId` for the URL? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe a little bit "hackish", but you could use :

```php
preg_match('/(src=".*")/', $sc_preview_embed, $match);
$sc_preview = str_replace($match[0], rtrim($match[0],'"').'&buying=false&download=true"', $sc_preview_embed);
echo $sc_preview;
```

outputs :

```html
<iframe width="100%" height="166" scrolling="no" frameborder="no" src="https://w.soundcloud.com/player/?url=https%3A//api.soundcloud.com/tracks/110090423&buying=false&download=true"></iframe>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use preg_replace and match the src="(.+?)" (with everything within between the quotes). and replace is with src="$1YOUR-ADDITION-HERE". The $1 is the match that you found in the first part.

Answer (score 0):

The "easy" way to do it is by doing your replace in the middle of the string.

```
$sc_preview = str_replace('player/?url=','player/?buying=false&download=true&url=', $sc_preview_embed);
```

The "correct" way, is probably to extract the URL from within the embed, then use [PHP's `parse_url`](https://www.php.net/parse_url) to manipulate the query string, then replace it within the embed.

That should ensure that it doesn't mess anything up.

However, you may want to consider asking your users not to paste in the embed codes, just the URL.  That way you can construct the embed in exactly the way you wish.

Comment: Hi Terence, thanks for this - would you be able to give me an example of how I could construct the embed code from just the URL? I couldn't find an example online that uses the SoundCloud direct link like this: https://soundcloud.com/instrumentalbgm/power-on-through-instrumental

Comment: Ah, I just assumed the URLs would be simple. You can look them up using the SoundCloud API http://developers.soundcloud.com/docs#resolving